# VBA - SQL Output Parameter returning NULL

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have the below sub in VBA and I am trying to retrieve the value of the output parameter from the stored proc but it either returns null or an empty string

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub BrandewynTest()

     ' Create Command Object
     Set g_objCommand = New ADODB.Command
     With g_objCommand
         .ActiveConnection = g_objConnection
         .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
         .CommandText = "BrandewynTest"
         .Parameters.Refresh
         .Parameters(1) = "value"

     Set g_objResultset = .Execute

     Debug.Print .Parameters(2).Value

     End With

End Sub
```

Below is the stored procedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE BrandewynTest
         @value VARCHAR(50)
        ,@ouput INT OUTPUT
    AS

        IF @value = 'value'
            SELECt @ouput = 1
        ELSE
            SELECt @ouput = 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define all your parameters, both input and output. Generally you could define your parameters more strictly as well. See the below code:

```
Public Sub BrandewynTest()

Dim PRM As ADODB.Parameter
Dim iRetVal As Integer

 ' Create Command Object
 Set g_objCommand = New ADODB.Command
 With g_objCommand
    .ActiveConnection = g_objConnection
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "BrandewynTest"

    Set PRM = .CreateParameter("@value", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "value")
    .Parameters.Append PRM
    Set PRM = .CreateParameter("@ouput", adInteger, adParamOutput, , iRetVal)
    .Parameters.Append PRM

.Execute
iRetVal = CMD.Parameters("@ouput")

Debug.Print iRetVal

End With

End Sub
```

You could argue that having iretval as a variable is superfluous but you can pin it to the watch t

Comment: Thanks @daniel11994, this solved it. I also realised that assigning the .execute to my g_objResultset object was also causing issues.